# How to Implement onItemClickListerner for ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to implement `onItemClickListerner` for `ListView` (see code below);
When running it, i get this error:

```
Error:(32, 37) error: incompatible types: List cannot be converted to OnItemClickListener
```

**List.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class List extends Fragment {
 ListView list;
 String[] Winners = {
  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
  "D",
  "E"
 };
 OnSiteSelectedListener SiteListener;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
  list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment1);
  list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter < String > (getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Winners));
  list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  return v;
 }

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
  SiteListener.onSiteSelected(position);
 }
 public interface OnSiteSelectedListener {
  public void onSiteSelected(int i);
 }

 public void setRefrence(OnSiteSelectedListener siteListener) {
  this.SiteListener = siteListener;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your class need to `implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `List` class needs to implement `OnItemClickListener`. You've already implemented the `onItemClick()` method, so you just need to add the interface to the class declaration:

```
public class List extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implemented `onItemClickListerner` for your `ListView` like this

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // HANDLE WHATEVER YOU WANNA DO WITH LISTVIEW CLICKS HERE
        SiteListener.onSiteSelected(position);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call setOnItemClickListener without implements in your class. So You can fix it in below two ways.

```
public class List extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
```

OR

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```